# Can not install CA cert file into iphone simulator 9.3

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, ios-simulator

I try to install the .cer ca certificate file into iphone simulator 9.3 by drag and drop to simulator following with installation successful and verified certificate text shown during installation process.
But at the end in the setting>General>profiles it is empty and shows "No profiles are currently installed".
What's wrong with it? because I was doing during previous versions of simulator successfully.